# Cakephp 3.0 form element radio button selected issue

Tags: cakephp, radio-button

I am facing problem in edit mode.

The radio button is not showing as selected.

This is my code

```
    <div class="control-group required"><label class="control-label"><?php echo __('status') ?></label><div class="controls">
            <?php

            $attributes = array(
                'selected' => 1
            );
            echo $this->Form->radio(
                    'status', $statusData,$attributes
            );
            ?>
            <span id="error" class="error"></span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: use `val` or `default` instead of `selected`

Comment: Thanks. But None of your option worked.

Comment: `http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons`, read here made a mistake reading it as select instead of radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this please:

```
$attributes = array(
   'value' => '1'
);

$statusData = array(
   '1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'
);

echo $this->Form->radio(
   'status', $statusData,$attributes
);
```

Comment: Only the last option is checked for radio inputs. It is not working for me also.